# How to access php page from another computer both are connected in LAN

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I created my php page by netbeans ide and xampp server  and its running in local web browser as index.php.

now the problem is i want to access the index.php page by another computer and update mysql database, both are connected in lan.

Comment: If you're running it on XAMPP, it should be accessible on any computer in the network, by my understanding. Have you tried just going to the url that you go to on the original computer? E.g. localhost/folder/index.php

Comment: use ip address for accessing.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can access your server from other machine. In that case two issue is possible.
1. If you just need to access from local network
2. If you need to access from internet i.e. from anywhere on earth.

for 2 you would have to have real(public) IP address.

for 1: you can access only from local network. Local ip address is enough.

in both case you need to make a small change in `httpd.conf` file.

```
 #your root directory address in full 
<Directory "C:/Program Files/*/www">
 Order allow, deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

After changing, you need to restart your apache server. then you can access from out side your own machine

Comment: After saving this directory tag to my httpd.conf, the XAMPP control panel freezes when I start Apache service after modification. Any idea why this happens ?

Answer (score 1):

Take for example there are 5 PC's connected to Lan. The IP address to all the computer will be as:

```
PC 1 have IP Address 192.168.1.2

PC 2 have IP Address 192.168.1.3

PC 3 have IP Address 192.168.1.4

PC 4 have IP Address 192.168.1.5

PC 5 have IP Address 192.168.1.6
```

now take for example you have installed Apache or IIS in PC 1 which have an IP address of 192.168.1.2, now all the other computer connected to netowrk will be able to access your web directory from the address 192.168.1.2. via a web browser. this will work regardless of what PHP application you are using. it is your Web server which is responsible for routing incoming request not your PHP application :)

Answer (score 0):

Set an ip address to the PC running xampp server and access the application from other computer through this IP.

Answer (score 0):

create a virtual host of the project in the original pc, then on the other pc create a host entry by the ip address of the original pc and the virtual host name of the original pc. This virtual host name can be used in the other pc